# Fade shader in Unity HDRP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have an image I painted with the soft brush in PS - it has an alpha channel. Im using the standard HDRP lit shader and have blend set to alpha/transparent, but I only have an alpha clip option.

The old pipeline has a fade, so the alpha clipping isn't as abrupt. Is this possible in HDRP?

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck 'Alpha Clipping' in the material while retaining Transparent surface type and Alpha blending mode - this should make the image have smooth edges while retaining alpha blending. Alternatively, if you still want alpha clipping, manipulate the threshold slider underneath 'Alpha Clipping' checkbox (visible only when it's checked).

Tested on Unity 2019.1.12f1 with HDRP 5.16.1-preview

Comment: im not seeing these options - can you show a screenshot?

Comment: What im trying to do is mask a mirror-like material, so cant use shader graph